# Building tab component in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to get this tab component in function, using plain javascript. And I get the tab's content to display in the debug mode, where as after fully compilation it doesn't shows up on the browser(or the selected tab content appears as display set to none). Also I am applying class 'activeNav' on the selected anchor tag indicating 'active' state. Even here the class gets applied and vanishes after the page fully loads. Where am I going wrong?

```js
function selectTab(evnt, targetBlock) {
  var i;
  var elementList = document.getElementsByClassName("displayContent");

  for (i = 0; i < elementList.length; i++) {
    if (elementList[i].id === targetBlock) {
      elementList[i].style.display = "inherit";
    }
  }

  evnt.currentTarget.classList.add("activeNav");
}
```

```css
.displayContent {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  background-color: pink;
}

.active {
  display: inherit;
}

.activeNav {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a class="a" href="" onclick="selectTab(event, 'Tabtitle-1')">Tab title 1</a></li>
  <li><a class="a" href="" onclick="selectTab(event, 'Tabtitle-2')">Tab title 2</a></li>
  <li><a class="a" href="" onclick="selectTab(event, 'Tabtitle-3')">Tab title 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="Tabtitle-1" class="displayContent">
  <p>Content Block 1</p>
</div>
<div id="Tabtitle-2" class="displayContent">
  <p>Content Block 2</p>
</div>
<div id="Tabtitle-3" class="displayContent">
  <p>Content Block 3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The anchor tag is reloading the page.

You have to call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent page from reload.

```js
function selectTab(evnt, targetBlock) {
  evnt.preventDefault();
  var i;
  var elementList=document.getElementsByClassName("displayContent");

  for(i = 0; i < elementList.length; i++) {
    if (elementList[i].id === targetBlock) {
      elementList[i].style.display = "inherit";
    }
  }

  evnt.currentTarget.classList.add("activeNav");
}
```

```css
.displayContent {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  background-color: pink;
}
.active {
  display: inherit;
}
.activeNav {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a class="a" href="" onclick="selectTab(event, 'Tabtitle-1')">Tab title 1</a></li>
  <li><a class="a" href="" onclick="selectTab(event, 'Tabtitle-2')">Tab title 2</a></li>
  <li><a class="a" href="" onclick="selectTab(event, 'Tabtitle-3')">Tab title 3</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div id="Tabtitle-1" class="displayContent">
  <p>Content Block 1</p>
 </div>
 <div id="Tabtitle-2" class="displayContent">
  <p>Content Block 2</p>
 </div>
 <div id="Tabtitle-3" class="displayContent">
  <p>Content Block 3</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are clicking on an Anchor tag. The default behaviour of the anchor tag is reload and change the page.

You can need to prevent the default behaviour, you can do it like this:

```
function selectTab(evnt, targetBlock) {
  evnt.preventDefault();
  var i;
  var elementList=document.getElementsByClassName("displayContent");

  for(i = 0; i < elementList.length; i++) {
    if (elementList[i].id === targetBlock) {
      elementList[i].style.display = "inherit";
    }
  }

  evnt.currentTarget.classList.add("activeNav");
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you too!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set `display:none` to other tabs in a `else` condition...and for `activeNav` class remove it from other tabs using for loop

Also either use `evnt.preventDefault()` in javascript or `javascript:void(0)` in the `<a>` tags `href` to prevent the page reload

***Stack Snippet***

```js
function selectTab(evnt, targetBlock) {
  var i;
  var elementList = document.getElementsByClassName("displayContent");
  var anchorList = document.querySelectorAll(".a");
  for (i = 0; i < elementList.length; i++) {
    evnt.preventDefault();
    anchorList[i].classList.remove("activeNav");
    if (elementList[i].id === targetBlock) {
      elementList[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      elementList[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  evnt.currentTarget.classList.add("activeNav");
}
```

```css
.displayContent {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  background-color: pink;
}

.activeNav {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a class="a" href="" onclick="selectTab(event, 'Tabtitle-1')">Tab title 1</a></li>
  <li><a class="a" href="" onclick="selectTab(event, 'Tabtitle-2')">Tab title 2</a></li>
  <li><a class="a" href="" onclick="selectTab(event, 'Tabtitle-3')">Tab title 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="Tabtitle-1" class="displayContent">
  <p>Content Block 1</p>
</div>
<div id="Tabtitle-2" class="displayContent">
  <p>Content Block 2</p>
</div>
<div id="Tabtitle-3" class="displayContent">
  <p>Content Block 3</p>
</div>
```